# Azure REST API - subscription id

Tags: rest, azure

I am new with Azure - I have account , from java SDK I can create virtual machine , but I prefer to use the REST API, however i don't know from where to get the subscription -id.  How do I retrieve the Subscription ID programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you can find the subscription id programmatically but easier way for you to find it is by logging into Azure Portal. Here's how you can find it if you login into preview portal (https://portal.azure.com):

- Login into Azure Preview Portal.
- Click on `Subscriptions` menu item in the left hand menu bar.
- You will see a table for all subscriptions you have access to. You will see the subscription id there only (it's a GUID value).

[image]

Comment: You can use `List all subscriptions` Azure Resource Manager API to find it programmatically - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/dn790531.aspx. HTH.